# Alpha channel and specular map together

Tags: materials, transparency

I am trying to make this can label with some transparency around worn-out edges but I just cannot figure out how to add specular map to the texture at the same time. That *fac* slot is quite busy. Is there some way to do that with mixing?
[image]

Comment: Can you add your two images (spec and alpha). this is really really easy to do in cycles, just need to see what the images look like.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have an object just for the label, in this case use an 'add' shader to combine your diffuse and glossy shaders and connect them to the mix.

If you had only one object and your specular was supposed to be applied to metal parts only, then you could use a mix with the inverted alpha as factor.

You can mix and add shaders without limits so setting up these kind of material is preferable in some cases (if you wanted to add a texture that affects both the can and the label).

This is what I mean:
[image]

[image]

Comment: When posting images please crop them to keep only the relevant information. The node tree you propose is very hard to read like this.

Comment: I've reposted the images and my node setup should be readable now when clicking on it. Thanks.

Comment: So I did it somehow. I don't know how but it seems to be working just fine. I have also tried it as you have suggested but all of the colors are off. Am I doing something wrong with your node setup? http://i.stack.imgur.com/vSSwm.jpg http://i.stack.imgur.com/0z5aN.jpg

Comment: Please don't add glossy and diffuse shaders, always mix them. For energy conservation. Also for non-metal surfaces the glossy is always white, don't feed texture into it. You should look up some PBR shader materials and how they are setup.